# why my current project in reactjs included this "theme": "lessc --js src/App.less src/App.css", in package.json scripts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, package.json

when i run script "theme": "lessc --js src/App.less src/App.css", in package.json scripts by npm run theme what will happen to my react project?

Answer (score 1):

```
"theme": "lessc --js src/App.less src/App.css"
```

Please, find the explanation below :

`less --js` => This enables evaluation of JavaScript inline in `.less` files.

`src/App.less` => `App.less` file contains your styling code and being compiled to `App.css` file which is available in `/src` folder.

`src/App.css` => `App.css` is compiled file which contains your compiled styling code of `App.less` file and that file be auto available in `/src` folder itself.

**Example :**

*App.less*

```
@width: 10px;
@height: @width + 10px;

#header {
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
}
```

*App.css* (compiled file from `App.less` after running the cmd : `npm run theme`)

```
#header {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: so when i run the script theme”: “lessc --js src/App.less src/App.css” compiled css is copied to src/App.css . git file changes , how to prevent this src/App.css file to commit to git ?

Comment: @SreenathMP: to prevent src/App.css in git, you can add file in .gitignore file. Refer : https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-gitignore-file

Comment: that's ok . after making changes to App.css . will i need to convert back to App.less and commits to git ? how to deal with it ? or i can commit App.css without need to care about App.less ?

Comment: *after making changes to App.css* => you need not to make any changes in App.css file manually/directly.   *will i need to convert back to App.less and commits to git ? how to deal with it ?* => yes, if u need to do any styling change, u have to do in App.less , and then run the script cmd, it will automatically update your App.css file with new changes and then  you can commit App.less and push in git.       *i can commit App.css without need to care about App.less ?* => there is no need to commit App.css file in git, but it necessary to commit App.less file.